# How to solve persistence delay or error while handling event in CQRS and ES?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am trying to implement another DDD bounded context with CQRS and ES.

I wonder, given there is `CreateUserCommand` that creates `User` in my domain model (not a word about saving). Then it fires `UserCreatedEvent`.

I have two event handlers for that event:

- `PersistUserEventHandler` (updates state of app) and
- `SendWelcomeEmailEventHandler` (sends welcome email to user)

Now, I know, that:

1. Order of processing event in Event Handlers should not matter
2. Saving state should be detail, because source of truth is in my event store.

But, what if I do not want to send welcome email until my read model is fully updated? Because, what if for example process is delayed or some error occurs and I am not able to persist that user into read model right now? Then I do not want send that welcome email now, because if user clicked to for example link to his profile in mail, he would see "user does not exists".

I saw people are persisting changes through repository directly in command handlers (which would solve this problem), but that does not make sense with Event Sourcing, because I want to be able to replay all events (with event handlers for persisting only to prevent all other side effects) and get actual state of application in persistence layer.

Or should I listen to `UserCreatedEvent` only with event handler that actually persists it into read model and then raise in this event handler another event `CreatedUserSavedEvent` and all emails etc. would have been sent by their handlers?

I suppose NO too, because it reminds me some event hell and also if I get EventBus into some event handler, I am getting into circular reference problem which is just effect of that I am violating rule that every depencency should point down to lower components of my system and not the other side.

So, how is this usualy solved or am I missing something?

Comment: "PersistUserEventHandler (updates state of app) and" - the state of the app is updated in the event store. This handler only project it.

Comment: @Tom what are you using for an event store?

Comment: @guillaume31 I actually dont yet. I am now making this library up to date: https://github.com/beberlei/litecqrs-php and then i want to use it to store events probably in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - PersistUserEventHandler (updates state of app)

You might be mistaking Read Models for a homogeneous whole that accurately represents the current state of an application, i.e. a second source of absolute truth besides the event log.

I tend to see them more as a bunch of partial, opinionated parcels of state that may not all be updated at the same time and may reflect different truths.

I don't recommend taking read models as a source of data in another context than the use case they were designed for. In your example, `SendWelcomeEmail` should probably not rely on the User read model but only on the data contained in the `UserCreated` event.

Now you can share *code* between read model projectors and other types of event handlers to avoid duplication, but sharing data seems risky.

Comment: I know that eventual consistency is intended tradeoff according to CAP theorem. And that I should not be taking in consideration persistence layer while building my domain model. But everybody says "dont think about infrastructure layer, focus to your domain". Well, but now I have my domain model and I need to actually persist data / update my read model. And coincidentally my read model is MySQL, so yes, your point about "homogeneous whole" is right in that actually I wonder how to maintain relations, where I need to save in some order - first main "items" and then relaions.

Comment: So is that that MySQL does not suit well for this approach and I should surrender on FK? Because then I dont care whether main items are saved first or least. But is it really nescessary to give up advantage I am taking with foreign keys for my query model and other data analysis performance?

Comment: There are many advantages to denormalized tables (without FK's or joins) on the read side, and you're free to use them since consistency is no longer a constraint. I'm not sure why you would choose to keep a traditional relation-based set of tables instead. You're basically paying double toll for both a strongly consistent state-based model and an event sourced model if you do that.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense since all my validation is done in code and i update read model just with actual facts, why would I need to constraint anything there on dabase level.

Answer (score 1):

If users have random UUID then it should not be a problem. If a user arrive at an url and the readmodel is not up to date then you could show a "loading in progress,please wait" message.

If you *really* want to know if the user *really* exists - for example you want to see the difference between "user does not exists" and "read model is not sunchronized yet" then you could send a special command that don't generate any events (or just test a command if your command dispatcher supports dry running of commands) and throw exception if user does not exist.

Comment: They already have, but, how do I know that read model is not up to date, respectively difference between "uuid does not exists" and "uuid not yet synchronized"? And, what if I need to have `AddBonusCreditOnCreatedUserEventHandler` and give newly created user some credit immediately after create? It can happen that I will be trying to add credits to user that not exists yet in my read model (I do not have write model, respectively it is event store). How to deal with that?

Comment: @Tom `AddBonusCredit` seems like a command (on the same model) and commands are processed by the write model that is always consistent. The events generated by this new command are processed after the `UserCreated` event so there is no problem.

Comment: But why should I need to know, that when I call `CreateUserCommand`, I should also call `AddBonusCreditCommand` to enforce bussiness logic that says "we add 10 extra bonus to every newly registered user"? :) Am I just going too far here and should let my application service orchestrate this?

Comment: @Tom isn't this your business logic? Anyway `AddBonusCreditOnCreatedUserEventHandler` looks like a Saga command handlerand what Sagas do? They create command based on events.

Comment: Yes it is, but encapsulation into application service does not correspond with what I am learning in DDD that business logic should be enforced in domain model. I also would not be happy introducing domain services since i like that my system exposes its usecases purely through commands. Or am I too "lets have it nice" here?

Comment: I have not heard about sagas until you pointed out, but AFAIK, they sounds like solution to my problem. I need to read further about it to find out. I wonder when i actually write some code :)))

Comment: If this is the solution mark it please :)) . If you have any other problems you can contact me